# How to append an HTML code block multiple times using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an HTML code block (a heading, some li tags followed by a link) which has to be displayed multiple times as search results in which each block is one result.

I get it as JSON in js. How can I loop over the JSON object and create, append multiple search results into the HTML page using plain JavaScript in the best possible way?

Note: I used to do it using directives in Angular.js

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before you post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do it using plain javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend going back to AngularJS, Knockout, or another MV* platform to accomplish this, but if you must do it in plain JavaScript, a basic approach is in the example here.

```js
var data = [
  {
    title: "First result",
    information: [
      "Jerry",
      "George",
      "Elaine",
      "Kramer"
    ],
    link: "http://example.com"
  },
  {
    title: "Second result",
    information: [
      "A",
      "B",
      "C"
    ],
    link: "http://example.com"
  },
  {
    title: "Third result",
    information: [
      "D",
      "E",
      "F"
    ],
    link: "http://example.com"
  }
];

var i = 0, j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i]) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    var title = document.createElement('h2');
    var items = document.createElement('ul');
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    
    title.innerHTML = data[i].title || "";
    
    if (data[i].information) {
      for (j = 0; j < data[i].information.length; j++) {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        
        item.innerHTML = data[i].information[j] || "";
        items.appendChild(item);
      }
    }
    
    link.href = data[i].link || "";
    link.innerHTML = link.href;
    
    container.appendChild(title);
    container.appendChild(items);
    container.appendChild(link);
    
    document.body.appendChild(container);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Knockout. Knockout provides data-bind property for HTML tags and it has foreach loop. So Knockout will loop through your JSON object and create,append multiple search results in to html page.

Comment: Please share your code sample, I can able to update and share Knockout code for the sample.